# XMLHttpRequest readyState HEADERS_RECEIVED waiting for entire file to download

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the `XMLHttpRequest` `readyState` event fires 5 events, listed below.

```
0    UNSENT              open()has not been called yet.
1    OPENED              send()has not been called yet.
2    HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3    LOADING             Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4    DONE                The operation is complete.
```

This would seem to suggest that the `HEADERS_RECEIVED` would be available before the entire file has downloaded, especially during a long transfer. However, in my testing, while the events do fire in this order, both `HEADERS_RECEIVED` and `LOADING` fire at virtually the same time as the `DONE` event.

Here is a basic example that illustrates my issue. The `OPENED` event fires immediately, but `HEADERS_RECEIVED`, `LOADING`, and `DONE` all wait 5 seconds. I ran this test with PHP 5.5 on a local Apache 2.4 server in both Firefox and Chrome.

**JavaScript:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log("readyState:", xmlhttp.readyState);
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "handler.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**handler.php:**

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
echo "start\n";
sleep( 5 );
echo "end\n";
```

It seems the only way to get the headers before the content is to first make a `HEAD` request, then a full request. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Using a 1GB file symlinked over a slow network share, or a PHP file that outputs a substantial amount of output (example below) does fire the `HEADERS_RECEIVED` sooner. This seems to be somewhat unreliable though. I've tried using PHP's [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function before `sleep`, but it doesn't help.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
echo "start\n";
$i = 10000000;
while( $i-- ){
    echo "1\n";
}
echo "end\n";
```

Is there a way to reliable send headers without waiting for the content to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the case of your example, I'm guessing PHP isn't actually flushing the buffer (and thus sending the headers) until after the sleep, but I'm not sure if that would explain this behavior if you've encountered it using actual file downloads.

Comment: I believe that the output buffers in PHP are only flushed with `ob_flush()`, I don't believe `flush()` will do so. Try using `ob_flush()`.

Comment: Interesting. It was my understanding that `ob_flush` was only necessary if you programmatically use `ob_start` but it turns out that PHP may (always?) automatically create a level of output buffering. It seems you can detect this by calling `ob_get_level` and checking if it is non-zero. `ob_flush` by itself isn't enough though. It seems you have to first call `ob_flush`, _then_ `flush`, to first flush the internal buffer, then send it to the client. This makes things more complicated, but thanks for the help!